# I need to put hyperlinks to all cells in the different Excel Book using Python openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, hyperlink, copy, openpyxl

I can't understand how to put external links correctly.

I'm expecting that links to cells will be related to their location.

I tried this

```
import os

from openpyxl import load_workbook, Workbook


def main():
    input_workbook_path = r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Hendler Python\1\1_Goals.xlsx"
    output_workbook_path = r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Hendler Python\Test.xlsx"

    input_wb = load_workbook(input_workbook_path)
    output_wb = Workbook()

    sheet_in = input_wb["Sheet1"]
    sheet_out = output_wb["Sheet"]
    cell_column = ["A","B","C","D"]
    input_workbook_path1=r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Hendler Python\1"
    input_sheet_name=r"1_Goals.xlsx"
    
    
    for i in cell_column:
        for row in range (1,6):
            for column in range (1, 6):
             external_cell_link = f'=\'{input_workbook_path1}\[{input_sheet_name}]{sheet_in.title}\'!${i}${row}' 
             sheet_out.cell(row = row, column = column).value = external_cell_link
    
    output_wb.save(output_workbook_path)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Please show us your code!

Comment: using an `r string` is acceptable.  the `\` or `/` also depens on the operating system...  for windows i tend to omit the `r""` and just use double backslash ` \\ `

Comment: the files are related to locations.  the links to cells are related to the files and sheets that they reside on.